# What's the difference between system() and execve()

Tags: c, system, setuid, execve

I use linux and c.

**First**, I soft link bin/zsh to sh

**Second**, I login as **root** the run the following program.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 char *v[3];
 if(argc < 2) {
  printf("Please type a file name.\n");
  return 1;
 }
 v[0] = "/bin/cat"; v[1] = argv[1]; v[2] = 0;
 /* Set q = 0 for system(), and q = 1 for execve */
 int q = 0;
 if (q == 0){
   char *command = malloc(strlen(v[0]) + strlen(v[1]) + 2);
   sprintf(command, "%s %s", v[0], v[1]);
   system(command);
 }
 else execve(v[0], v, 0);
 return 0 ; 
}
```

**Third**, I login as a **normal** user(not root). 
Now, I can remove or rewrite a file which I don't have **write** privilege by using the execute file of this program.

Like this:

```
./a.out text;\`echo \”Not right\”>text\`”
```

Now I can write "Not right" into the file "text". I only have read privilege of this file

[image]

The read and write privilege of these files.
[image]

**Fourth**, I change q to 1. That means, this time I use execve instead.

And do the same thing as above.
But this time I cannot change the content of the file.

Why? 
I google in the internet, but I can not find the different between system and execve.

Comment: Do you mean what is the difference *besides* the fact [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) runs a command *and then* returns to the caller, while [`execve`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve) replaces the caller's process data with the the called process, thereby having no "return" state to the caller (because there is no caller anymore) ?

Comment: Do you mean execve is using the normal user privilege but system is using root privilege?

Comment: The command you say allows you to overwrite a file without the required permission has unballanced (and weird) quotes. It won't do what you mean as is (the `echo` part won't be run by your program as it is). There's something wrong with your tests, execve or system doesn't change anything wrt privs. (Add a `printf` right before `return` in main to see a difference between system and execve.)

Comment: I'm doing a lab test using system() and execve() to see if the system can be attacked. The echo part did change the file which a normal user do not have a write privs. But I can't figure out why.

Comment: @littletiger Can you edit to fix the exact command-line. Should the quotes be mismatched like that?

Comment: @luserdroog Can you see the command-line? I put a screenshot.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for fixing that. Are you sure about the permissions? What's the output of `ls -l text` before and after the change?

Comment: I put a screenshot of ls -l. I forgot to say that I set "chmod 4755 to a.out".

Comment: As a note, permissions are about the actual files, not the link. To unlink a file, it's irrelevant if you have write permission for it, you must have write permission for the containing folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system` invokes a shell to parse the string and handle quoting and variable interpolations and stuff. `execve` does none of this. It replaces the program with the called program and passes the argument strings exactly as specified; ie. it will not interpret quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You said you did `chmod 4755 a.out`. That means you're setting the `setuid` bit and the program will then always run with root privileges, and has write access to `text`. The string with backquote is passed to the shell which interprets it as a command to write to `text`.

The reason `execve` doesn't write to text is that it doesn't interpret its arguments as a shell command and ` doesn't have any special meaning.